# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to add some extra information to my Devise User model like first_name, last_name, age, gender and city.

When I fill the signup form and click to submit I get this error:

SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: users.first_name: INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

```
def each
  loop do
    val = step
    break self if done?
    yield val
  end
```

And these are the parameters if they are any use:

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"2e5oUwMw84HtwSuI09X1O5kjPLYk7SW4VKgGOOxcB93W7sSQYjPgq3N/BGo0+oAEifhec4lQ3PUt9vub17vs7g==",
 "user"=>
  {"first_name"=>"Test", "last_name"=>"Test", "age"=>"69", "city"=>"New York", "gender"=>"Trans", "email"=>"test.test@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}

Here is my schema.rb just in case:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.string   "first_name",                          null: false
    t.string   "last_name",                           null: false
    t.integer  "age",                                 null: false
    t.string   "city",                                null: false
    t.string   "gender",                              null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

Here is my user.rb model too:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have additional columns on user not already set in devise I allowed access in my ApplicationContoller this way. Rails4

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  # Only add some parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation).concat [:first_name, :last_name]
end
```

or

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :full_name
end
```

and this would allow you to have first_name last_name with the other things that you have set up.

Rails5

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  additional_params = [:name, :company, :email_confirmation,   {addresses_attributes: [:address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zip, :country, :name]}]
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: additional_params)
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: additional_params)
end
```

Comment: Hi @Jake, thanks for the help so far. I tried both of the code excerpts you have provided and bot give me an: undefined method `for' for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0x007fa5a1020208>

Comment: isaacsloan in the next answer says that Strong params is giving me problems because of the can't be null. Should I just do a migration removing can't be null? Thanks for the help. This is my 3rd web-app ever lol

Comment: What version of rails and devise are you using? Also just to double check did you put this code inside of your app/controllers/application_controller.rb

Comment: Yup the code went into application_controller.rb. I'm on rails 5.0.1 and devise 4.2.0

Comment: I have added/edited my answer. The last code snippet is working inside of our rails 5 app on the same devise version. It uses the .permit instead of the .for

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a unique index on email. What the error is saying is that the email you are trying to save is not null in the database. A user already has this email. Change the email and it should work.

```
  # to check for the user in the database 
  rails c 
  user = User.find_by_email("test.test@email.com") should bring back a user.
```

Comment: Looks l like what is happening is that first_name can't be null. Strong params is filtering it out though so when he tries to save it is null. @jake's answer above looks like it will fix that.

Comment: Hey @isaacsloan do you think I should do a migration removing can't be null from the extra params and just doing a .require in the form?